# How to Use a list in razor as DropDownListFor without using viewbag or selectlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a model that include a list of another model.Now,I try use it in partial view page as a dropdownlistfor.I don't want use viewbag or selectlist.Do I need to write a helper ?

**Product Model**

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? Code { get; set; }

    public int? ProductGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductGroup ProductGroup { get; set; }

    public List<ProductGroup> ProductGroups { get; set; }
```

**ProductGroup Model**

```
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }


   public int? THoldingAdminsId { get; set; }

   public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }


   public int? Code { get; set; }



   public string CName { get; set; }
```

I want display a list of productgroup in product form as a dropdownlistfor.
any help ?

Comment: To which Model, your view is strongly bound?

Comment: I want some thing like this :   @html.dropdownlistfor(model=>model.ProductGroupId,Model.PrpductGroups)

Comment: I know you want something like this. But If your View is strongly bound to **ProductGroup** model then you can't assign the property of other model **Product** in View.

Comment: oh no,I use this in view : @model  model.entity.Product

Comment: The `DropDownListFor()` method accepts `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as the 2nd parameter, so its `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductGroupId, new SelectList(Model.ProductGroups, "Id ", "CName "))`. Why are you saying you do not want to use `SelectList`?

Comment: I mean exactly this was,I don't knew that should be cast it.Thanks.

Comment: What you should be doing is using a view model with property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductGroups`. You should not use a data model in a view when editing - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank u so much